# Docker-compose container access to host TCP server

Tags: python, docker, pyspark

I'm currently learning docker and I have some problems understanding how to access and expose ports container.
I have a custom docker-compose with spark container that works just fine, what I want is to run a python script locally in my PC (OS: Windows 10), the script starts a TCP server and sends a word each 0.5seconds.

From the master spark container I want to access the TCP server port and process the text, but i'm having problems since I'm not able to connect the spark container to my local server.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  spark-master:
    build:
      context: ./spark
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: "spark-master"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - "7077:7077"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./data:/data
      - ./output:/output

  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.1
    container_name: "spark-worker-1"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no

  spark-worker-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:3.1
    container_name: "spark-worker-2"
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
```

The python script executed in my PC:

```
import socket
import time

host = 'localhost'
port = 9999

servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

servidor.bind((host, port))

servidor.listen()

print(f"Server TCP/IP: {host}:{port}...")


while True:        
    conexion, direccion = servidor.accept()    
    print(f"conexion: {direccion[0]}:{direccion[1]}")    
    
    while True:
        palabra = "HELLO"
        conexion.sendall(palabra.encode())
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The script runned in master-spark container:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName= "miDstream")
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    ssc= StreamingContext(sc, 10)

    inputStream= ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9999)

    nuevoDStream = inputStream.map(lambda record: record.upper())
    nuevoDStream.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` refers to the Spark worker container, when using Docker, not your host.

You need to use [`host.docker.internal`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds-for-all-platforms) instead from the Spark code.

Sidenote: Make sure your code works when not using Docker, first. That's not a requirement for Spark.